# Combine multiple drawables

Tags: android, drawable

I have multiple drawables and want to combine it to one drawable (for example, 4 squares to create one big square, like Windows logo :)). How can I do this?

Comment: Here is the Developer's Guide on [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html). It discusses this is great detail with pictures and runnable code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do that using a `TableLayout` or some `LinearLayout`s. However, if what you want is to create a single image to usin within a `ImageView` you will have to create a `Bitmap` manually; it is not hard:

```
Bitmap square1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square1);
Bitmap square2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square2);
Bitmap square3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square3);
Bitmap square4 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square4);

Bitmap big = Bitmap.createBitmap(square1.getWidth() * 2, square1.getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(big);
canvas.drawBitmap(square1, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(square2, square1.getWidth(), 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(square3, 0, square1.getHeight(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(square4, square1.getWidth(), square1.getHeight(), null);
```

I have not even compile the code above; I'm just showing you how it can be done. I'm also assuming you have square drawables all with the same dimensions. Notice that the bitmap called `big` can be used wherever you want (e.g. `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`).

Comment: Thanks, and how do I create the drawable with this canvas?

Comment: What do you mean by drawable? A `Drawable` class instance? If so, you can use `BitmapDrawable`. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course Drawable class. 4 input Drawable instances and one output.

Comment: Yes, then you can use `BitmapDrawable`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) to do exactly this.